# Building Node.js API (Unexpected Token error mongodb connection using standard MongoDB URI)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mlab, db.js

1)  config/db.js :

```
   module.exports = {
      url: 
   mongodb://username:password@ds159400.sample.com:89400/databasename
   };
```

2) Error log:

```
    url: 
   mongodb://username:password@ds159400.sample.com:89400/databasename
          ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
      at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
      at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
      and so on....
```

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

The popular solution which doesn't work 
Making the URL under quotes like this

db.js:

```
    module.exports = {
      url: 
    `mongodb://username:password@ds159400.sample.com:59400/databasename`
    };
```

Error log
Directory referenced in the error is ../node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:255 and the error below

Error log:

```
    throw err
        ^

    TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
        at MongoClient.connect
        ... and so on
```

Comment: try changing the url to a string: `url: "mongodb://username:password@ds159400.sample.com:89400/databasename"`

Comment: Error log: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

Comment: hi suhaid, pehchane kya

Comment: you cant directly give string without quatation

Comment: please add your mongo client syntax

Comment: i have updated my answer

Comment: can you add codesnippet with the part where you call mongoclient.connect?

Answer (score 2):

Need to quote connection string.

Also for configuration purpose,provide credentials from confg json.

```
module.exports = {
   url:  `mongodb://${userName}:${userPass}@${mongo.host}:${mongo.port}/${mongo.database}`
}
```

In your case,it should be

```
module.exports = {
      url: 
   `mongodb://username:password@ds159400.sample.com:89400/databasename`
   };
```

Comment: I got this error  "TypeError: Assignment to constant variable."

Comment: @SuhaibAskar which line number? Please share relevant script.Its not related to this

Comment: I have edited the question with the relevant reference. Kindly see through it.

Comment: @SuhaibAskar please add connect statement as well

Answer (score 0):

1.)**config/db.js**

with string

```
 module.exports = {
          url: "mongodb://username:password@ds159400.sample.com:89400/databasename"
       };
```

with literals

```
let username = 'username';
let password = 'password';
let dbhost = 'ds159400.sample.com';
let port = '89400';
let dbname = 'databasename';

module.exports = {
    url: `mongodb://${username}:${password}@${dbhost}:${port}/${dbname}`
};
```

2.)**server.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongourl = require("./Config/db.js");
mongoose.connect(mongourl.url);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```